# PYROCMS custom module routing is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, pyrocms

This is my routing code.

```
 $route['news(/:num)?'] = 'news/index$1';
 $route['events(/:num)'] = 'news/events$1';
```

this is my Controller code.

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
     exit('No direct script access allowed');

class News extends Public_Controller
{
   public function __construct()
   {
      parent::__construct();

      parent::__construct();
      $this->lang->load('news');
      $this->load->helper('url');
  }


  public function index()
  {
        $data = 'index call';
       // Build the page
       $this->template->title($this->module_details['name'])
            ->build('index', $data);
  }

  public function events()
  {
      $data = 'events call';
      // Build the page
      $this->template->title($this->module_details['name'])
            ->build('index', $data);
  }
}
```

`http://example.com/news` this url is working.

`http://example.com/events` this url is not wokring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stacked before same issue and found the solution.

#### Solution is modification the `application/config/routes.php` file.

Because of module routes working only when it's running. You have to routes file that allways running, that file is system `routes.php` So first segment of routes should be module name in module routes file.

*For `/news/722/hello-world/` url:*

```
$route['news(/:num)?'] = 'news/index$1'; // This will work

$route['events(/:num)'] = 'news/events$1'; // This wont work
```

If you want to change routing `events`, you have to modify `application/config/routes.php`

**My discussion PyroCMS Forum:**

https://forum.pyrocms.com/discussion/25301/navigation-link-to-module-with-custom-routing